# How to create an HTML list from flat XML file using XSLT (based on earlier question)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to create HTML unordered lists from a flat XML structure using XSLT 1.0. The input XML consists of a series of nodes to be transformed into list items. However, this series may be interrupted by non-list nodes of different types:

```
<input>
  <paragraph>abc</paragraph>
  <paragraph>def</paragraph>
    <listable>123</listable>
    <listable>456</listable>
  <other-block>
    <other-text>Foo</other-text>
  </other-block>
    <listable>789</listable>
    <listable>012</listable>
</input>
```

My objective is:

```
<div class="output">
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>def</p>
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>456</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="my-block">
    <p class="other">Foo</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>789</li>
    <li>012</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I found a [old thread with a solution that almost works for me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3919416) (last solution on the page, by Dimitre Novatchev) and adapted it. This is a minimal stylesheet based on that solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM: -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- NON-LIST ITEMS: -->
    <xsl:template match="input">
        <div class="output">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="paragraph">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="other-block">
        <div class="my-block">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::other-text" /> 
        </div>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="other-text">
        <p class="other">
            <xsl:copy-of select="text()" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- LIST HANDLING: -->
    <xsl:key name="kFollowingUL" match="listable" 
                use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::listable)][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::listable) and following-sibling::*[1][self::listable]]">

        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />

        <xsl:variable name="vFolUL"
                select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())"/>

        <xsl:if test="$vFolUL">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
                        select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())" />
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="listable" mode="copy">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
        </li>
    </xsl:template>   

    <xsl:template match="listable" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem with this approach is that it does not apply transformations to the last non-listable node before each list. The `<paragraph>` and `<other-block>` nodes in the input are copied directly to the output, although templates are applied to descendants of `<other-block>`:

```
<div class="output">
  <p>abc</p>
  <paragraph>def</paragraph>
  <ul>
    <li>123</li>
    <li>456</li>
  </ul>
  <other-block>
    <p class="other">Foo</p>
  </other-block>
  <ul>
    <li>789</li>
    <li>012</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to modify the earlier XSLT 1.0 solution and add transformation of the last nodes before the listable groups?

Comment: Rather than just writing the code for you, we'd prefer to be able to answer a specific question you have about how to do something.  With that in mind, it would be helpful if you could provide a **[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, along with a specific question from you about how something does or does not work.  For instance, I don't know what you don't know.  In addition, I tried applying Dimitre's code to your sample input, and I got different output from your post.  So please also post what XSL you are using.

Comment: I modified my question to include a working example of the input, XSLT, and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <div class="output">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="other-block">
    <div class="my-block">
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </div>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="other-text">
    <p class="other">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listable">
    <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::listable])">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="list"/>       
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listable" mode="list">
    <li>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::listable]" mode="list"/>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I would also do it that way. You could even get rid of `xsl:if` instruction ussing the test in the template and having an empty template for a `listable` element in general.

Comment: This answer works for me. Thank you for sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem came from this template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::listable) and following-sibling::*[1][self::listable]]">

    <xsl:call-template name="identity" />

    <xsl:variable name="vFolUL"
            select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())"/>

    <xsl:if test="$vFolUL">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
                    select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

This match any element with a `listable` element as the first following sibling. Then in the content template it calls the template named `identity` (in this case, it's the identity rule). This has better [**default priority**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#conflict) than the other template for `other-block` elements:

```
<xsl:template match="other-text">
    <p class="other">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I like michael.hor257k solution wich is the approach I gave in the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3919682/11102282).  Another possible solution would be to follow the same principle:

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(self::listable) and following-sibling::*[1][self::listable]]">

    <xsl:call-template name="separator" />

    <xsl:variable name="vFolUL"
            select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())"/>

    <xsl:if test="$vFolUL">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"
                    select="key('kFollowingUL',generate-id())" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="other-text" name="separator">
    <p class="other">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

But, do note that this doesn't scale well.